# maintain the scroll position when drop down list is click (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

i have option value and onclick function which send data to another page.

but after i do select for the drop down list, the scroll bar of window is at the top.

I need maintain the scroll bar position of window at current row after do selected.

Comment: Could you provide some code/fiddle or image of the problem?

Comment: If you use ajax on your page you can try to store the current scroll position in session of PHP and retain the position on the next page.

Comment: You refresh the page or you send data to another page?

Comment: Do you mean the scroll bar position of the page or the select list contents?

Comment: <option value=\"1\" ".$proceed." onClick=\"window.location='index.php?pages=job&job_id=".$row->job_refno.';\">Proceed</option>                  @feddus

Comment: @Christiaan , i still new in ajax.

Comment: @xpy, not refresh , is me send the data. but the thing will appear in same page just selected option will change

Comment: @JoshHarrison, scroll bar position of the page

Comment: Unless you have some other code that you haven't posted, `window.location` is not ajax. It causes the browser to request and load an entirely new page.

Comment: @JoshHarrison, sorry for late reply. I didnt apply ajax, I just use php and javascript.

Comment: the current pages is called paging and the function is link to (index.php?pages=job...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have an ID attribute on the select menu, add one. Something like this:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown"> ...
```

Then change all the option tags to something like this:

```
<option value=\"1\" ".$proceed." onClick=\"window.location='index.php?pages=job&job_id=".$row->job_refno."#dropdown';\">Pro‌​ceed</option>
```

Adding #dropdown to the end of the window.location redirect url will scroll the window to your element with ID `dropdown` on page reload.

Comment: can apply this coding in order to find scroll bar position ?             x = window.pageXOffset; 
   y = window.pageYOffset;

Comment: how to add one more onclick function ?